# Movement to reduce "ing" to "in"

Tags: pronunciation, orthography

let's face it. More and more people are not saying the silent "g" at the end of swimming, speaking, cooking etc.

When will the "ing" become just "in"?

It's already used in almost every song, because "g" is hard and almost impossible to sing.

Any revolutionary movement to eradicate "ing" and bring "in" into English out there?

Comment: That’s not the way language change works. Even when pronunciations change, as they certainly do, changes in spelling rarely follow.

Comment: *g* is **not** impossible to sin.

Comment: Wanting to adapt written English to the way it's pronounced would take a lot of doing and would end up changing most of the written language (why specially focus on -ing?). One of the specificities of English is the great discrepancy between spoken and written forms. Adapting English spelling to its pronunciation isn't revolutionary, it's been tried for [ages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_spelling_reform). And it might have economic consequences if we can tell from this page from the [English Spelling Society](http://www.spellingsociety.org/betterspelling/why-is-spelling-so-difficult).

Comment: And for further indication that the ŋ is not necessarily more difficult to pronounce than the n, consider the Malayan _oran utan_, which became _orangutan_ in English. My opinion is that equating ŋ with n is so common in song, because you have more words you can rhyme it with.

Comment: @Kris: I've spent the last half hour searching for the meaning of the phrase "impossible to sin" (your above comment), tried an improbable relation with "dead to sin" and others, and just realised it must be a simple pun I was very slow in taking - or just a forgotten *g*. If you could confirm though it would really put my mind at rest!

Comment: @MrLister It's dropped in songs not because of more rhymes on "in", but because "G" is not possible to sing, the same as "b". but you can sing a,e,i,o,u,and some other sounds like the humming which could be interpreted as "n". Well, unless you are a professional beatboxer, then you can maybe "sing" b and g and k etc. ;D

Comment: That makes little sense... you can sing any speech sound that is sonorant. /ŋ/ is *definitely* sonorant. But that's beside the point, because it's never syllabic in English anyway. You only ever sing syllable nuclei when singing - saying it's not used in song because it's not possible to sing (like b and k etc.) would mean that you can't sing ANY non-sonorant consonants. Does that then mean we may only sing vowels and nasals (and the odd lateral)? I think you need to rephrase your question or consider again what you mean.

Comment: @Laure: G is not impossible to sing(g). Without the "G" you would have *sin* in its place, as Kriss smartly points out... but, but it's not the present participle or the gerund form. The song: [**Singin' in the rain**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0045152/) sounds perfectly acceptable AND it's the exact title of the film.

Comment: This is a loaded question. Can you provide evidence for your claim? Otherwise it is just an example of recency illusion, we can plain reject it as such and be done.

Comment: I think people are getting the orthography and the pronunciation mixed up...

Comment: Derfder back to your old ways! :) First, insisting that the English language doesn't need indefinite articles, then there had to be a historical movement for the abolition of the definite article. English is changin' and evolvin' before our very eyes. No movement, or revolution is needed; they're just not the ones you would like to see!

Comment: There is absolutely no need here to change the spelling, because it's a perfectly regular change … the suffix *"-ing"* is unambiguous is the written language, and whether you pronounce it /ɪn/, /ɪŋ/, /in/ or /iŋ/, all the verbs with the suffix *"-ing"* are pronounced the same way. The situation is analogous with the suffix *"ed"*. Even among spelling change proponents, "correcting" the spelling of the suffix *"-ed"* is of low priority because there are easy rules to determine how it's pronounst, and if you always speld it the way it was pronounst, you'd end up with three different spellings.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the [Recency illusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recency_illusion), as mentioned by Reg.

Comment: Voting to close as Not Constructive.  Again.

Comment: There has never been a *g* pronounced at the end of *sing*, nor for that matter in the middle of *singer* either — unlike in *finger*.  You don’t understand how English gets the way it is, so you want to change it. You would have a better chance of tilting at windmills, which is all you seem to doing here. It doesn’t make any sense and is a waste of time, too.

Comment: @Laure I'm back just now, so sorry to have kept you guessing. After all, yes, it *was* a pun, you guessed it right.

Comment: @tchrist You say "There has never been a g pronounced (..) in the middle of singer", but you'd be surprised at the regional variances you can find... there _are_ people in England who do pronounce it just like "finger".

Answer (score 2):

The premise is simply wrong. /ɪn/ has a different consonant from  /ɪŋ/: there is no "reduction" involved.

Modern English has two grammatical forms ending  *-ing*, one a verbal noun (eg *I like swimming*) and the other a participle, or verbal adjective (eg *I thought about it while swimming*), but historically the latter derives from a form in *-en*, and has fallen together with the other form; so some confusion between /ɪn/ and /ɪŋ/ goes right back before the beginning of Modern English.

I don't know whether /ɪn/ for /ɪŋ/ has been increasing, but I rather doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost not harder at all to say, especially if the next consonant is velar (i.e. /g/ or /k/). The reason people say /ɪn/ as opposed to /ɪŋ/ or /iŋ/ at all is because the two morphemes *-ende* and *-inge* as a verb suffix essentially merged but some people favoured one pronunciation over the other, but it didn't ever hinder meaning.

To this day different dialects use different variants as a result and some even use both in free variation (like me). It's hardly "easier to say" as much as it just *comes more naturally*, because we've heard it and used it growing up. I doubt it would be heard so much if the only pronunciation were /ɪŋ/, if at all. I'm not ruling out the possibility of it becoming /ɪn/ an as eventual development, though.

There is more to read here, if you like: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonants#Phonological_history_of_ng

As Barrie said, the orthography is very very unlikely to follow.